# Magento How to get The Parent Category of A Sub-Category from A Product

Tags: magento, tree, parent, categories, product

```
Root Category (id: 1)
 - Apparel (id: 2)
   -- Shirts (id:4)
   -- Pants  (id:5)
 - Accessories (id: 3)
   -- Handbags (id:6)
   -- Jewelry (id:7)
```

On Magento we can get the category Ids of a product by using `$productObj->getCategoryIds()`

```
$productObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$categoryIds =  $productObj->getCategoryIds();
```

Which will return an array of category Ids of the product. I have a specific need to get the first level parent of category of a product. Takes for example the category tree above, if a product is categorized in **Pants** category, I want to get the first level category which is **Apparel** (in this case, the product only tagged under **Pants** category but not tagged in **Apparel** category).

Question: what method can I use to get the parent category of a sub category, or is it possible to get the first level category from a product?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `catalog/category` model and its method `getParentCategory()`:

```
foreach ($categoryIds as $iCategoryId) {
    $m = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->load($iCategoryId)
        ->getParentCategory();
    var_dump($m->debug());
}
```

Comment: Please forgive my small edit. It is better to use `debug` than `getData` because `debug` recursively converts contained objects to arrays and hides their private members. It also avoids infinite loops that would consume all memory.

Comment: @clockworkgeek: No problem. I'm aware of `debug()` and you're right. The `getData()` thingy comes from my IDE `var_dump` macro. Failed to change that to `debug()` for years now^^ Not anymore. Thank you^^

Comment: I have a `Mage::log()` macro. I guess great minds think alike ;)